# display working out of order in Chez Scheme

Tags: chez-scheme

I'm using chez 9.5.4 on a Mac.

The following code:

```
;; demo.ss
(map display (list "this " "is " "weird "))
```

does this:

```
$ chez --script demo.ss
weird this is
```

Why the accidental Yoda?

How do I prevent this?

It works as expected in Chicken Scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As answered by u/bjoli on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/scheme/comments/ojh7cw/help_display_working_out_of_order_in_chez_scheme/h51kgxa/?context=3):

> Your code is relying on unspecified behaviour: The order of map is unspecified.
>
> You want for-each.
>
> Chez has no stack overflow (like racket or guile). Doing a right fold with map means no (reverse ...) At the end. It is faster, except in some continuation-heavy code.
>
> Schemes without the expanding stack optimization all do a left fold. Like chicken.

Comment: Chicken doesn't stack overflow either, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that this is just what `map` does.

According to the r7rs-small specification, on page 51 of https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf :

> The dynamic order in which proc is applied to
> the elements of the list s is unspecified.

That's because `map` is intended for transforming lists by applying a pure function to each of their elements. The only effect of `map` should be its result list.

As divs1210 quotes u/bjoli in pointing out, Scheme also defines a procedure that does the thing you want. In fact, `for-each` is described on the very same page of the r7rs-small pdf! It says:

> The arguments to for-each are like the arguments to map,
> but for-each calls proc for its side effects rather than for
> its values. Unlike map, for-each is guaranteed to call proc
> on the elements of the list s in order from the first ele-
> ment(s) to the last, and the value returned by for-each
> is unspecified.